# Check if NDsolve solution of nonlinear second order eq. is random

Tags: differential-equations, random, nonlinear

I'm solving second order nonlinear eq. using NDsolve. I'm interested in y'(t) dynamics (plotted below). The thing is - from this solution I'm not sure if we have some randomness or it is just complex multiperiodic solution. Any ways to check if it is random or not?

```
\[Xi] = 0.694;
Tm = 1000;
i1 = 1.6;
\[CapitalOmega] = 0.46285714285714286;
sol = NDSolve[{{\[Xi] y''[t] + y'[t] + Sin[y[t]] - 
       i1*Cos[\[CapitalOmega] t] == 0}, y'[0] == 0, y[0] == 0.2}, 
   y, {t, 0, Tm}, MaxSteps -> Infinity, MaxStepSize -> 10^{-2}];
Plot[y'[t] /. sol /. t -> o, {o, 0, Tm}, PlotRange -> All, 
 PlotStyle -> {{PointSize[0.0045], Red}}, ImageSize -> 600, 
 Frame -> True]
```

[image: Solution y'(t)]

N.B. Poincaré map of the solution:

```
data = Block[{}, 
    Reap[NDSolve[{\[Xi] y''[t] + y'[t] + Sin[y[t]] - 
         i1*( Cos[\[CapitalOmega] t]) == 0, y'[0] == 0, y[0] == 0.2, 
       WhenEvent[Mod[t, (2 Pi)/\[CapitalOmega]] == 0, 
        Sow[{Mod[y[t], 2 Pi], y'[t]}]]}, {}, {t, 0, 10 Tm}, 
      MaxSteps -> Infinity, MaxStepSize -> 10^{-2}]]][[-1, 1]];
ListPlot[data, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Map]

Answer (score 1):

The squared magnitude of the Fourier coefficients can be obtained by "Periodogram". For your example:

```
Periodogram[dat, ScalingFunctions -> "Linear",  PlotRange -> {{0, 0.1}, {0, 1000}}]
```

[image]

You see that there is a strong DC peak, some low frequency noise and a strong single frequency.

Comment: How is *"noise"* defined here? Isn't the equation deterministic?

Comment: You can get chaos from a deterministic system

Comment: Not my topic, so sorry if I'm off the charts here, but isn't the difference between *"noise"* and *"chaos"* that *"noise"* is **stochastic** while *"chaos"* is deterministic? I don't see how this is stochastic, the *"randomness"* the OP asks about puzzles me.

Comment: Noise here means many different frequencies with low amplitude..

Comment: So signal consists of periodic part and some noise part? How I can be sure this is not some NDSolve rounding error tho?

Comment: Increase working precision and check if something changes.

Comment: Setting WorkingPrecision->5 leads to error:

:At t == 3.603970082489486656398773368`5.*^-11, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected

Comment: WorkingPrecision=5 is way too low. Set it to16, 24,32,..